# What to do with the unused Ethernet pairs?

Tags: ethernet

What's the general rule for unused Ethernet pairs (I couldn't find a solid answer online)? I have a gigabit Ethernet coming in, however, I only need the RX and TX pairs. What do I do with pairs 4/5 and 7/8? Is there any termination required?

Thanks

Comment: Gigabit uses all 4 pairs....

Comment: Normally the outer pairs are used. The inner pairs are grounded at the destination port. Unused pairs should be grounded to avoid noise pickup.

Comment: And for those of us who are lazy, adventurous and half insane, you use the unused pairs for phone lines or a second network jack.  But as @cde said if you want gig speed you have to properly wire so ...